# PHP cookie удаляется раньше срока

Tags: php, cookie

Всем привет!
Буду благодарен за пинок.
После логина создается сессия и cookie сроком 1 месяц setcookie 2592000.
Но буквально через несколько часов, если ничего не нажимать, сессия убивается.
Скрипт готовый и рабочий - если не кастомизировать HTML (заменяю шаблон), все работает шикарно.
Может быть, что из-за другого шаблона и версии jquery что-то ломается в сессиях?

Comment: Какой HTTP-заголовок `Set-Cookie` в итоге получается-то?

Comment: какая связь то? сессия не вечна, он и должна удаляться на сервере через заданный интервал бездействия. При чем тут куки?

Comment: setcookie ( "user_id", $_COOKIE ['user_id'], time () + 2592000, "/", "." . $config ['domain'] );

Comment: в шаблоне родном мб ajax запросы чего на сервере запрашивают вот сессия и висит, а в новом если бездействие, то она и отпадет. куки тут вообще не при делах

Comment: session_destroy только по нажатию logout.

Comment: "в шаблоне родном мб ajax запросы чего на сервере запрашивают вот сессия и висит, а в новом если бездействие, то она и отпадет. куки тут вообще не при делах"  а вот это кстати интересно. В родном шаблоне есть ajax запрос, но он к jquery 1.8.1 на Google

Comment: вы в браузере ф12 инструменты откройте и сетевую активность xhr посмотрите, все запросы там и увидите, какие были в старом шаблоне